# How can I reduce a lvalue bus without an extra signal?

Tags: system-verilog

I have a module with a multi-bit signal:

```
output  logic [2:0]  tuser,
```

In the module instantiating it, I only have a single bit signal and it should be the *reduction OR** of the modport.

- Is there a way to do a **reduction-OR** (`|sig`) directly with the **streaming operator** `{>>{}}` or any other technique?

**Example:** (obviously wrong)

```
logic single_bit;
 .tuser  ({>>{|single_bit}})
 .tuser  ({|>>{single_bit}})
 .tuser  (|single_bit)
```

I'm trying here to use the language's power here instead of having a separate signal just to do the reduction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately SystemVerilog does not have the syntax that expresses what you want to do. The only operators defined to work as the target of an assignment (known as an *lvalue*) are concatenation and the streaming operators. Those only map positional bit associations. You have to define an extra signal for anything beyond that.